# Check a field in model in generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am writing a rest API. this is my view:

```
class OrderDeleteAPIView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderDeleteSerializer
    # permission_classes = (OwnerCanManageOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

and this is its model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True)WAITING = 'WA'
    PREPARATION = 'PR'
    READY = 'RD'
    DELIVERED = 'DV'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (WAITING, 'waiting'),
        (PREPARATION, 'preparation'),
        (READY, 'ready'),
        (DELIVERED, 'delivered'),
        )
    status = models.CharField(
      max_length=2,
      choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
      default=WAITING,
    )
```

and:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    customer_email = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is its serializer:

```
class OrderDeleteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

What should I do if I want the object(order) can be deleted, only when the status field is 'waiting' ?

Comment: Please next time check the indentation before posting.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement some checks, in the `destroy` and return an error message as response in case the constraints are *not* met:

```
class OrderDeleteAPIView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderDeleteSerializer
    # permission_classes = (OwnerCanManageOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'id'

     def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        if instance.status != Order.WAITING:
            return JsonResponse(
                status=412,
                data={'status':'false',
                      'message': 'status should be WAITING'}
            )
        super(OrderDeleteAPIView, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Of course you can return any sort of answer (not *per se* a JSON response, nor does the status has to be 412). Usually HTTP status code 412 means that [**412 Precondion failed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412).

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about permissions, but it is a close situation.

If you want to check permissions, there is a way to do this via overridden `check_permissions`:

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class OrderDeleteAPIView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderDeleteSerializer
    permission_classes = (OwnerCanManageOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'id'

    @lru_cache
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Order.objects.get(self.kwargs['order_id'])

    def check_permissions(self, request):
        # this method will call OwnerCanManageOrReadOnly first
        super().check_permissions(request)
        # and then do other checks
        instance = self.get_object()
        if instance.owner != request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
```

As you can notice, I use `@lru_cache` to cache `get_object`. The reason to use it is because after `check_permissions` there will be another method (in this case `retrieve` or `destroy`) which will call this method again. To reduce database requests count I use caching.